# Apply language standard to just part of a source file?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Is it possible to enforce a C or C++ language standard for just part of a source file?  I want to ensure that my source file is C90 compliant, but it depends on some headers that require C99.  The compliance of those headers isn't important to me right now (I can compile with C99 for the time being), but I want to minimize effort required to port my code to a more restrictive platform in the future.

In short, I want a language standard to apply to the entire file except for the included headers.  Given how header inclusion works in C and C++, I figure that the general problem is to apply a language standard to an arbitrary portion of a given source file.

I'm working with GCC in particular, but I'm also curious if this is possible with other compilers (msvc, clang).

Comment: But you know that there are some things relevant to whole files, "interactions" between source files, and whole programs too, in the standard? Parts of source code files do not exist in their own vacuum.

Comment: What is the point of it?

Comment: @EugeneSh. -- the idea is to use the compiler to enforce standard compliance.  Even if it's not feasible to overhaul all of the file's dependencies to conform to C90 now, it would be useful to be able to assert that the source file under development doesn't use language constructs unsupported by the old standard.

Comment: If you require C90 compliance then it is in your best interest to get there completely and as soon as possible.  The headers used by a given source file are not a separable piece whose compliance you can ignore -- they affect the interpretation and possibly the language conformance of the rest of the file.  The sooner you bite the bullet and make everything conform, the less work that task will take.

Comment: Wouldn't source that is C99 compliant automagically be C90 compliant?

Comment: @Great.And.Powerful.Oz -- I think you've got that the other way around.  Code that's C99 compliant may use language constructs and features that aren't present or allowed in C90.

Comment: @JackO'Reilly, of course. ahh, wait, durrrr. Of course. Got it.

Comment: Pay no attention to the man behind the curtain.  @Great.And.Powerful.Oz.

Comment: @Great.And.Powerful.Oz: There are incompatibilities, resp. clarifications in  C99 compared to mideval C (more for ancient C). And there might be problems arising from passing C99 constructs to the older version. Briefly: that cannot be answered without a full review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make sure your code is C90 compatible while still relying on headers that use C99, you can enable the GCC warning flag `-Wc90-c99-compat`.  This allows you to use C99 features, but emits a warning wherever you use features not available in C90.  To avoid generating these warnings in your header files (which are presumably correct), enable the warning using a pragma, after you include the files.

This will basically achieve what you want.  The warnings will only be emitted for the code you specify.

```
#include "myheader.h"

#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wc90-c99-compat"

void func(void) { ... }
```

A stricter version would be to use:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wc90-c99-compat"
```

As far as I know, Clang is mostly compatible, but MSVC doesn't really support C99 that well to begin with so you're on your own.

Comment: Marked this as accepted since it solves my problem directly (to warn / error on compatibility issues for arbitrary sections of code).  Apologies to Jesper Juhl, whose answer technically addresses the question as asked more directly.

Comment: An additional note: ironically, this only theoretically solves my problem, as the warning flag noted here is only present for GCC 5 and beyond -- sadly unavailable on my platform.  Still, one could enable the warning and assert compliance by testing a compile with a newer GCC.

Comment: @JackO'Reilly: GCC 5 will probably arrive on your platform pretty soon.

Answer (score 3):

No. You cannot build a file (compilation unit) as partly one language standard and partly another.

What you *can* do however is split the file into two files and compile each of them using different language standards (just be sure that it is then still well defined to link both object files afterwards).

A better solution would be to ensure that *all* the code complies with the newer or older language standard and then just use that.

Comment: An alternative solution would be to ensure all code compiles with the older language standard, and just use that.   That means converting the headers to avoid C99 features.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I considered splitting the file into two, but won't the file with the stricter compliance still need to include the same headers and run into the same problem?

Comment: @Peter Sure, but if you have to edit the code to comply with either older or newer standard it seems counterproductive going forward to aim for the older.

Comment: @Jack O'Reilly Maybe. That depends on what headers are needed by either of the new files. I'd say that going for making all the code compile with the same language standard is the most sane way forward that will cause the fewest headaches going forward. Including fixing your headers if you insist on the older standard.

Comment: @Jesper - if the requirement is to build compilation units as C90 (e.g. to maintain backward compatibility so it is possible to build on a system with no C99 compiler) then the requirement becomes "avoid C99 features", not "update to newer language standard".

Comment: @Peter Right. But C90 is 26 years old by now, so maybe OP should reconsider that requirement and go for C99 (or even C11) instead ;-)

Comment: @JesperJuhl if only!  This requirement wasn't my idea.

Comment: @Jesper - The OP has said he needs to maintain C90 compliance.   We don't know if that requirement is an arbitrary choice on his part, or something that is beyond his control.   If it is beyond his control, a suggestion to update to C99 is useless, and options to maintain C90 compatibility are needed.

Comment: The problem with splitting is when it comes to header files with class/method templates for which one cannot create separate compilation units...